# Styling radio button group

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with a number of radio buttons, each set of buttons are in a radio group (three per group).

What I am trying to do is come up with a css solution that has the following:

- radio_button_0 - red backgrond when clicked
- radio_button_1 - red background when clicked
- radio_button_2 - grey background when clicked

Is there a way to make this happen, many thanks in advance for your help?

```css
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
 display:none;
}

input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:-2px;
 padding: 4px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #333;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
 vertical-align: middle;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
 border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

 input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
 color: #FFF;
 background-image: none;
 outline: 1;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

```html
<tr>
 <td><div id="condition">Item 1</div></td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="Item1" value="0" id="Condition_0" class="styled"/>
  <label for="Condition_0">SW0</label>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="Item1" value="1" id="Condition_1" class="styled" />
  <label for="Condition_1">SW1</label>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" name="Item1" value="" id="Condition_2" class="styled"/>
  <label for="Condition_2">Clear</label>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Add an `ID` to `radio_button_2` and target it that way.

Comment: @Chris Yongchu, there is already an ID for radio_button_2

Comment: Then target it like this `#Condition_2:checked + label { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target your `#Condition_2` input by id:

```
#Condition_2:checked + label {
    background-color:grey;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/u6baqfse/

Comment: Perfect. I did not know that was going to be so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Since you have now posted the *actual* HTML this solution will no longer work.**

Ensure that the radio button group is wrapped and use the `nth-of-type` selector like so:

```
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label {
  background-color: #CC0000;
}
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label {
  background-color: #00cc00;
}
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label {
  background-color: #0000CC;
}
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label,
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -2px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#e6e6e6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
  outline: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label {
  background-color: #CC0000;
}
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label {
  background-color: #00cc00;
}
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label,
input[type=checkbox]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label {
  background-color: #0000CC;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Radio Button Choice</legend>


    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">Choice 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">Choice 2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-2" />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">Choice 3</label>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```